# Conditionally add columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to calculate some statistics and return the results as another data.table. I can do this using the following.

```
DT <- data.table::data.table(station = rep(1:1,52560), mod = rnorm(1*52560),obs = rnorm(1*52560))  # 1year , 1 station

stat <- DT[,.(minObs       =  min(obs),
          minMod       =  min(mod),
          maxObs       =  max(obs),
          maxMod       =  max(mod),
          meanObs      =  mean(obs)]
```

however, my problem is that I want to add these stats conditionally. For example, only if meanObs exists in vector of requestedStats, 
add the column meanObs. The reason is that I am calculating quite a number of statistics and the length is huge and I want to give the user the choice of the statistics. How can I do that? Assume

```
requestedStats = c("maxObs","meanObs")
```

Just to add as requested. I want to avoid calculating all statistics. Only the ones requested should be returned.

Comment: Is it an option to calculate all stats but only return those in the vector?

Comment: @newbie You should edit your post to reflect your answer to docendo's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid computation of all the stats up front, you'll need to put each stat that might be named into a list. The list has to be quoted so that R doesn't try to evaluate it until needed.

```
my_exprs = quote(list(
    minObs       =  min(obs),
    minMod       =  min(mod),
    maxObs       =  max(obs),
    maxMod       =  max(mod),
    meanObs      =  mean(obs)
))

w = which(names(my_exprs) %in% requestedStats)
DT[, eval(my_exprs[c(1,w)])]
#     maxObs      meanObs
# 1: 4.51951 0.0009352312
```

Comment: That's a nice solution

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.